# Why we prefer to send User credentials, JWT token in headers?

Tags: authentication, jwt, access-token, credentials

Why do we prefer to send User credentials and JWT token in headers?

I am working on a proejct where i have to send user crednetials in header. But i don't understand why can't we use request json (payload) instead of header?

Answer (score 0):

Various reasons. For one it is simply better to evaluate the request header before even considering the body. Think of it this way - if you send a letter to another person, the person will only get the letter if the letter is correctly addressed to him. If he required a verification of the sender (analogy of using tokens in requests) and it isn't there - we shouldn't open the letter.

Another reason is that for example get requests doesn't have a body. So you want to have the token placement streamlined for all requests types.

It is safe to include the token in the header as long as you use https, see [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/210056/is-it-safe-to-transmit-access-tokens-via-http-headers)

Comment: Thanks Jonas for your valuable reply. I got your point for token. But what about user credentials while doing login ? Can't we use my login API request JSON for credentials? As it will be a post request.

Comment: Yes you should send credentials in the body.